# Convert timestamp to month name only

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

I would like to change every timestamp in column of a dataframe into just the month name.

```
date =[]
month=0
for j in clean_data['created_at']:
    date.append(j)
    month = time.strftime("%b",time.gmtime(date))
print(month)
```

I have the following error:

> TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)

My expecting output is "Jan, Feb, Mar etc...". For example, I want  `2019-06-13T14:22:28Z` to just be `Jun`

Comment: Example:  I want this 2019-06-13T14:22:28Z to just be Jun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
clean_data['created_at']= pd.to_datetime(clean_data['created_at'])
clean_data['created_at'].dt.month_name().str[:3]
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. How would I run a loop to go through the whole column clean_data['created_at'] to convert all the timestamps in that column of the dataframe?

Comment: The two commands give you the new strings. If you want to replace the values, do `clean_data['created_at'] = clean_data['created_at'].dt.month_name().str[:3]` for the second line.

Comment: It works but I this this error when I run the program

SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Answer (score 0):

**TRY:-**

```
import datetime

# Getting month from the string
date_ = int("2019-06-13T14:22:28Z".split("-")[1])

# Extracting month name, from the number of the month
month_ = datetime.date(2000, int(date_), 1).strftime('%b')

print(month_)
```

**OUTPUT:-**

```
Jun
```